# Reporting Median and IQR in a manuscript

Tags: descriptive-statistics, median, reporting

I am writing a manuscript and needs assistance. When reporting median and IQR, can I add the ± to it? Or should simply state it as a median (IQR). Thank you.

Comment: My advice is to omit the $\pm$ and just present the IQR in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: Can I use **mean** and **median** on the same table of results?

Comment: I don't see why not.